# What old version of Chrome browser does angular12 support at least

Tags: angular, angular-material

Can angular 12 support the chrome 53 kernel I use?

Is there any reference to the website or document, I would like to see it.

Why is Vue so popular in China???

Answer (score 0):

Angular supports the latest version of chrome. If you need support for older versions, you have to use "polyfill". You can read more about it [here](https://angular.io/guide/browser-support#polyfill-libs).

> why vue so popular in china

because the framework is written by Chinese person, that's literally the only reason.